# Is there a BibLaTeX equivalent for the BibTeX style "alphadin" for the DIN 1505 Standard

Tags: biblatex

A similar question was asked here before and I found [DIN 1505 conform .bbx and .cbx](https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505) but it doesn't look like the `alphadin`. The BibLaTeX alphabetic style sadly won't do it for my purposes.

So I tried to modify the files but failed.

I'm aiming for a look like this. It's basically din `.bbx` and `.cbx` combined with the alphabetic style.

[image]

Moreover the label for entries without an author should be the first 3 characters of the cite-key - just like `alphadin` would do it but alphabetic won't.

Does anyone know how to modify the files or a workaround for this problem?

Comment: There's a a DIN 1505 style for `biblatex` on [Github](https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505), though I have no idea how complete this implementation is. Not too much work seems to have been done on it.

Comment: yea thats the one I referenced up there - it doesn't do the full job

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to add in your question what exactly is missing? Or with other words can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) including a bib file (use package `filecontents`for this) showing what you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More information is certainly needed to specify an alphabetic style, but the document below gives a start. It requires biber as the backend.

Here `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` specifies an alphabetic label format that largely corresponds to one of the following, ordered by precedence:

- `shorthand` field
- the `label` field, plus the last two digits in `year`
- first three letters of the surname in the (truncated) `labelname` list when it contains only one item, plus the last two digits in `year`
- first letter of each surname in the (truncated) `labelname`, plus the last two digits in `year`
- first three letters of the entry key

If the length of `labelname` exceeds `maxalphanames` it is truncated to a list of length `minalphanames`. The default option settings are `minalphanames=1` and `maxalphanames=3`. Truncation is indicated in the label via the `\labelalphaothers` character:

```
\newcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{+}
\newcommand*{\sortalphaothers}{\labelalphaothers}
```

These can be redefined with `\renewcommand*`. The `\sortalphaothers` variant is used only for sorting and should be redefined if `\labelalphaothers` uses any formatting commands. Details on `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` and `\defbibenvironment` can be found in the biblatex manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=din]{biblatex}

% Use cite/entry key as fallback label
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
    \field[final,strwidth=3]{citekey}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}

% Add labels to bibliography - taken from alphabetic.bbx
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{bit:kiel,
  title = {Arbeitsgruppe Angewandte Informatik (Wirtschaftsinformatik)},
  url = {http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/bit/},
  year = 2012}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct,companion,aksin,cms,kant:ku,bit:kiel}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this looks right - thank you - I will try that out - if this works it should be added to the 'din'-style so that it would be the new 'alphadin' for 'biblatex'!

Answer (score 0):

Use `[style=alphabetic]` when importing, like:

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

Note that his solution does not comply to DIN 1505. It simply achieves a similar style to that of

```
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
```

So this does not answer the question asked above, but since I found this question when trying to find the solution my answer provides (I figured it out somehow), it might help other people landing here.

Comment: could you show an example on how this could be applied?

Comment: Note that that will only give you something that is broadly the same as `alphadin`, in that it is an alphabetic style. Many details will differ from `alphadin` by default and if you really want DIN 1505, some more work is needed. See Audrey's answer and https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505

Comment: @moewe thank you for clearing this up. I was not aware of the requirement to comply to DIN 1505.

Comment: @Raaja this answer is for People that are already using `biblatex` but want to use the style of `\bibliographystyle{alphadin}`in `bibtex`. Simply add `[style=alphabetic]` to the import.

Comment: @felixmp Can this be used by anyone who uses a `biblatex`? Please make your solution complete. Right now this is just a piece of script, which only a few knows or understands where/how to use it.