# Tabular Layout for natbib fields

Tags: natbib

I'm using the natbib package and as a styling I'm using dinat.
Which results in this:

[image]

However I'd like to have a consistent tab between the [König 2018] and the rest so that it looks like a two column layout.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{SemVer}
\bibliography{literatur}{}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\end{document}
```

literatur.bib:

```
@misc{SemVer,
    author       = "Preston-Werner",
    year         = "2018",
    note         = "verfügbar unter: https://semver.org/"
}
```

Desired Ouput

```
[König 2018]             König, Lily: 2018 - verfügbar unter: 
                         https://semver.org even more text eveb more text
[Preston-Werner 2018]    Preston-Werner: 2018
```

and so on. Any idea in how to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should try `alphadin` or biblatex with audreys solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124612/29873